# Join and Change Display value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, select, case

The database tables are follows:

Employee Table:

```
Emp_NO: E01
Name: StackOverflow
JoinDate: 01012020
EndDate: 05052020
Department_ID(FK): D1
Shift_ID(FK): 1

Emp_NO: E02
Name: OverflowStack
JoinDate: 01012020
EndDate: 06062020
Department_ID(FK): D2
Shift_ID(FK): 1

Emp_NO: E03
Name: FlowStackOver
JoinDate: 01012020
EndDate: 04042020
Department_ID(FK): D3
Shift_ID(FK): 1
```

Shift Table:

```
Shift_ID: 1
Shift_Code: 001
Shift_ref: reg001-k
Description: MorningClass
```

Department Table:

```
Department_ID: D1
Title: RT
Description: Research Team

Department_ID: D2
Title: DT
Description: Development Team

Department_ID: D3
Title: Admin
Description: Admin
```

As above, I would like to perform a total result with joining `Employee table` with `Shift table` via `Shift_ID`
Query:

```
SELECT Employee.No, Employee.Name, Employee.JoinDate, Employee.EndDate, Employee.Department_ID, Employee.Shift_ID, Shift.Shift_Code, Shift.Shift_ref, Description
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN SHIFT ON Employee.Shift_ID = Shift.Shift_ID
```

For `Department` however, it required to display `Title` as `R&D` (Research and Development) for those `Employee` whose `Department` is `D1` and `D2`, it is like joined department.
In this case, D3 will remains the same.

Expected sample result(Employee + Department):

```
E01, StackOverflow, 01012020, 05052020, D1, 1, R&D, Research and Development
```

Finally join all three table result as (Employee + Shift + Department):

```
E01, StackOverflow, 01012020, 05052020, D1, 1, 001, reg001-k, MorningClass, R&D, Research and Development
E02, OverflowStack, 01012020, 06062020, D2, 1, 001, reg001-k, MorningClass, R&D, Research and Development
E03, FlowStackOver, 01012020, 04042020, D3, 1, 001, reg001-k, MorningClass, Admin, Admin
```

I had hard time for showing the above result, can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want a `case` expression:

```
select 
    e.no, 
    e.name, 
    e.joindate, 
    e.enddate, 
    e.shift_id, 
    s.shift_code, 
    s.shift_ref, 
    case when d.department_id in ('D1', 'D2') 
        then 'R&D' 
        else d.department_id 
    end department_id,
    case when d.department_id in ('D1', 'D2') 
        then 'Research and Development' 
        else d.description 
    end description
from employee e
inner join shift s on e.shift_id = s.shift_id
inner join departement d on d.department_id = e.department_id
```

Comment: Hi @GMB I believe I need to have two `case` right? One is for `department_id` and another one is for `department.description` respectively

Comment: Hi @GMB I submitted an update, I think it is more suit to my situation? the `department_id` on the second case should be `description` (?)

Comment: oh wait, I think both way work what I am thinking is `case when d.description in ('Development Team', 'Research Team') then 'Research & Development' else d.description`

Comment: Excellent work @GMB. Just that you missed the alias for shift table in case some lazy ass wants to copy and execute the query straight away :)

Comment: @AnkitMahajan I dun even noticed that , I automatically added during I rewrite